# Url.Action not able to match a route

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in my Mvc controller I have the following action with a defined route

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("OrderLineSchedule/{salesOrderId}/{webOrderId}/{orderLineNumber}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> OrderLineSchedule(string salesOrderId, int? webOrderId, int orderLineNumber)
    { 
//code 
    }
```

In one view I have the following link trying to cree the url using with Html.Action helper method.

```
 <a href='@Url.Action("OrderLineSchedule", "Orders", new { area = "account", SalesOrderId = Model.SalesOrderId, WebOrderId = Model.WebOrderId, OrderLineNumber = Model.OrderLineNumber})' id="lnkOrderLineSchedule">@Model.Quantity @Model.ActivityName</a>
```

The problem is - only in one occasion when `Model.SalesOrderId` property is null - in this case Url.Action  is not able to  construct any url pointing to this action. I will appreciate any hep

Answer (score 0):

Make sure MapMvcAttruteRoute before MapRoute in RegisterRoutes. and your Controller names should be OrdersController

[image: MapMvcAttruteRoute - Location]

Comment: ALready done that - as I mentioned the PROBLEM ONLY occurs if model.salesOrderID is null